# Why does Resnet18 seem to not be learning?

Tags: python, pytorch, resnet

I'm working on a binary classification network in Pytorch. I have two folders with 200-250 images each, each image being about 500 pixels in height and width (they vary), one folder labeled "ai_images" and the other "artist_images", and I want to use transfer learning with Resnet18. However, I'm getting 40-65% accuracy even after training for several epochs.

I checked if the model was learning anything by first changing all the labels from [1,0] if the image is ai and [0,1] if not to just [0,1] for all of them, which Resnet was getting 100% accuracy with after 20 datapoints.

However, when I changed the labels back and instead divided all the RGB values of the ai images by 10000, Resnet was back to giving 40-65% accuracy.

At this point I'm not sure if using Resnet doesn't work for this problem, if I'm implementing it wrong, or if it's how I load the data.

###### MAIN.py

```
model =  models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
# add a fc network to the end of resnet so it only has 2 outputs
model_ = Network()
model.fc = model_
print(model)

#loads training data
train_data = training_data()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

test_size = 25

for epoch in range(20):
    print(f'starting epoch {epoch+1}')
    correct = 0
    for i in range(train_data.__len__()):
      image,label = train_data.__getitem__(i)
      image = image.unsqueeze(0)
      label = label.unsqueeze(0)
      output = model(image)
      loss = loss_fn(output,label)

      if torch.argmax(output) == torch.argmax(label): correct += 1

      if i%test_size == test_size-1:
        print(f'{str(correct/test_size*100)[:5]}%', str(loss.item())[:5])
        correct = 0
      
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()
      

print('Finished Training')

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model.pt')
```

###### detector_network.py

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
```

###### data_loader.py

```
class training_data(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  ##Characterizes a dataset for PyTorch
  def __init__(self):
        ##Initialization
        print('Getting Data')
        self.data = []
        ai_images_filenames = glob.glob('ai_images/*.png')
        artist_images_filenames = glob.glob('artist_images/*.png')
        
        for img in ai_images_filenames:
          img = self.formatImg(img)
          label = torch.tensor([1,0]).type(torch.float)
          self.data.append([img, label])

        for img in artist_images_filenames:
          img = self.formatImg(img)
          label = torch.tensor([0,1]).type(torch.float)
          self.data.append([img, label])      

        random.shuffle(self.data)
          
        print(f'{len(self.data)} samples')

  def formatImg(self,img_path):
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    # converts img to np and removes transparency values
    img = asarray(img, dtype=np.float16)
    img = img[:,:,:3]
    # converts np to torch and makes the channel value the first one
    img = torch.from_numpy(img).type(torch.float)
    img = np.swapaxes(img,0,2)
    # resizes and crops for resnet
    img = fn.resize(img,size=[224])
    img = fn.center_crop(img,output_size=[224,224])
    return img

  def __len__(self):
        ##Denotes the total number of samples
        return len(self.data)

  def __getitem__(self, index):
        ##Selects one sample of data
        return self.data[index]
```

Comment: Some potential issues: resnet18 expects a specific input range for its images (see https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.resnet18.html). You have to rescale the images and then normalize them. You're not using a dataloader, and your batch size is 1. This creates noisy gradients that might prevent the network from learning. Without a nonlinearity (ReLU), having projections `fc1` and `fc2` is equivalent to just having a single `Linear(512, 2)`. This probably wouldn't break training though. Finally, resnet18 might just not have enough capacity for your task.

Comment: I am also confused from what exactly is your target. What do you mean by "change the labels back"? And why divided by 10000? I agree with DefinitelyNotAPlesiosaur, normalization is important, and using a dataloader would probably help! However, It should be fine with [0,1] and [1,0] (you can also use a single output with 0 for ai and 1 for artist, using for example sigmoid as activation function). And what is `fn` from where you call `fn.resize`? Maybe check that the data is prepared correctly (opencv resize function usually works fine)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I used a dataloader, which definitely helped (and I think there is a bug in my old code for data loading). I have the project working now and I realize the design was flawed in many ways, from using resnet to collected really biased data because of the site I was using. As for why I was dividing by 10000, I only divided one set by 10000 because I was wondering if the code would work if it was differentiating from normal images and pretty much completely black ones. I think the question is pretty irrelevant to the solution, so I'm thinking of taking this down soon.